# DateTime gives error with table types sql c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, user-defined-types

I have the following lines of code:

```
//Function that returns the following metadata
List<SqlMetaData> data = new List<SqlMetaData>();
data.Add(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.BigInt));
data.Add(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
data.Add(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
data.Add(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("Date", SqlDbType.DateTime));


//Function that builds the record and fills it with data
SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(data.ToArray());
record.SetInt64(0, this.Id);
record.SetString(1, this.Name);
record.SetString(2, this.Description);
if (this.Date.HasValue) {
    record.SetDateTime(3, this.Date.Value);
} else {
    record.SetDBNull(3);
}


//Important piece of the function that sends the data to the sql server
using (SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", conSql)) {
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //data is IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
    tvpParam = cmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@CollectionName"), data);
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    TypeName = ("dbo.NameType");
    cmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It gives the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string. The data for table-valued parameter "@CollectionName"
>   doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error
>   is: 241, state: 1 The statement has been terminated.

This seems weird because I just pass the DateTime. What could be the problem here?

@edit 19:09 21-10-2016 -> SQL Table definition
My Used Defined Table Type is as follows:

```
ID, Bigint null
Name, nvarchar(max), null
Description, nvarchar(max), null
Date, datetime, null
```

@edit 20:21 21-10-2016 -> Stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateName](
@NameCollection [dbo].[NameType] READONLY)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- Existing items
        INSERT INTO [datatable].[dbo].[Name]
                   ([Id],
                    [Name],
                    [Description],
                    [Date])
         SELECT 
                [FC].[Id],
                [FC].[Name], 
                [FC].[Description], 
                [FC].[Date]
        FROM @NameCollection AS [FC]

    IF @@trancount > 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        SELECT 1  as 'errorNumber'
             , 0  as 'errorSeverity'
             , 0  as 'errorState'
             , '' as 'errorProcedure'
             , 0  as 'errorLine'
             , '' as 'errorMessage'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    SELECT  error_number()  as 'errorNumber',
            error_severity()    as 'errorSeverity',
            error_state()       as 'errorState',
            error_procedure()   as 'errorProcedure',
            error_line()        as 'errorLine',
            error_message()     as 'errorMessage'
IF @@trancount > 0 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Maybe the fields on the DB aren't defined as datetime but as nvarchar?

Comment: data cannot be passed as @CollectionName

Comment: Any chance the DateTime is not nullable?  I'd also look for a mismatch between the DB's DateTime format and the System.Globalization.CultureInfo DateTimeFormat in your code.

Comment: @Gusman I've added the table definition. (Forgot to add)

Comment: Hmm, you're using a stored procedure, can you post its code (the rest of the code seems to be ok)?

Comment: @Gusman added the stored procedure!